# Как сделать адаптивное направление импульса прыжка, в зависимости от поворота спрайта Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Начал изучать **C#** и **Unity2D**. Решил сделать небольшой платформер, где передвижение осуществляется только прыжками.Проблемы в том,что я не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы импульс прыжка прикладывался в направлении оси Y персонажа, даже при его наклоне. На данный момент,при наклоне влево или вправо, вектор прыжка направлен
по глобальной оси Y вверх, получается что персонаж прыгает вверх боком/под наклоном, а необходимо чтобы он прыгал в направлении головы. Прошу помочь разобраться, буду очень благодарен.

**Вот мой код:**

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float  hzSpeed;
    public float rotateSpeed;
    float speedX;
    float rotateZ;
    public float verImpulse;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    
    bool onGround = false;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

  void FixedUpdate() {
       
       if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){
           speedX = -hzSpeed;
           rotateZ = rotateSpeed;

       }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
           speedX = hzSpeed;
           rotateZ = -rotateSpeed;
       }

       if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)&&onGround){

            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(speedX,verImpulse),ForceMode2D.Impulse);

       }
       transform.Rotate(0,0,rotateZ);
        speedX = 0;
        rotateZ = 0;
   }
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground"){
            onGround = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) {
         if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground"){
            onGround = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
// обязательный компонент
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    // эти поля не должны быть public, SerializeField
    [SerializeField] private float _speed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float _jumpPower = 10f;
    [Space]
    // пустой прикрепленный GameObject у основания ног персонажа 
    // иначе _onGround можно получать от столкновения боком или головой
    [SerializeField] private Transform _groundCheck;
    // определять землю не через tag, а через layer
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask _groundLayer;
    [SerializeField] private float _groundCheckRadius = 1;
    private Transform _transform;
    private Rigidbody2D _body;
    private float _direction = -1;
    private bool _onGround = false;

    private void Awake () {
        _transform = transform;
        _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // каждый Update кадра
    private void Updata () {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            SetDirection(-1);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            SetDirection(1);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            Jump();
    }

    // каждый Update физики
    private void FixedUpdate () {
        if (_onGround == false && _body.velocity.y < 0 && CheckGroundCollide())
            Lending();
    }

    private void SetDirection (float direction) {
        _direction = direction;
        // направление персонажа в разные стороны делается не через поворот, а зеркальный скеил
        // поворот персонажа фризится в свойствах тела
        _transform.localScale = new Vector3(_direction, 1, 1);
    }

    private void Jump () {
        if (_onGround) {
            _body.AddForce(new Vector2(_speed*_direction, _jumpPower), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            _onGround = false;
        }
    }

    private void Lending () {
        _onGround = true;
        // обнуляем вектор тело, что бы не было инерции
        _body.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }

    private bool CheckGroundCollide () {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(_groundCheck.position, _groundCheckRadius, _groundLayer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо.Я ещё сам обнаружил,что определение столкновений через тег-плохая идея.Если коллайдер соприкасается одновременно с несколькими тегами,то условие перестаёт работать.Так же,можете объяснить почему нужно использовать именно `[SerializeField] private`,а не public?Что так, что так появляется поле в инспекторе.

Comment: Дело не в инспекторе, а нарушении инкапсуляции.